# Implement FileMangerBundle (artgris) using TinyMCE with Symfony3

Tags: javascript, symfony, tinymce

for my project I use FileManagerBundle of artgris. And i want to implement the windows in my view.twig, but i don't know where I need to create myFileBrowser().

This is my twig.html :

```
{% extends 'CoreBundle:Base:base.html.twig' %}


{% block title %}TEST DOWNLOAD{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 box-blanche-ombre">
            <div class="row boutontitre">
                <div class="col-md-6"> 
                    <h1>TEST DOWNLOAD</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% for type in ['primary','success', 'info', 'warning','danger'] %}
                {% for message in app.session.flashbag.get(type) %}
                    <p class="message bg-{{ type }}">{{ message|raw }}</p>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
            <form method="post" action="dump.php">
                <textarea name="content"></textarea>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var BaseURL = "{{ app.request.getBaseURL() }}";
    </script>
    <script src="{{ asset('Bootstrap-Confirmation-master/bootstrap-confirmation.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bootstrap-datepicker/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.fr.min.js') }}"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        tinymce.init({
            selector: '#mytextarea',
            file_browser_callback: myFileBrowser,
            theme: 'modern',
            height: 300,
            plugins: [
                'advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker',
                'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking',
                'save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor'
            ],
            toolbar: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | print preview media fullpage | forecolor backcolor emoticons'
        });

        function myFileBrowser(field_name, url, type, win) {

        var cmsURL = "{{ path('file_manager', {module:'tiny', conf:'tiny'}) }}";
        if (cmsURL.indexOf("?") < 0) {
            cmsURL = cmsURL + "?type=" + type;
        }
        else {
            cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=" + type;
        }

        tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
            file: cmsURL,
            title: 'File Manager',
            width: 1024,
            height: 500
        }, {
            window: win,
            input: field_name
        });
        return false;
    }
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

This is the link to the doc, if you have a idea, thank you !

https://github.com/artgris/FileManagerBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/tutorials/integrate-tinymce.md

Ho yeah, I can access to mywebsite.com/manager/?conf=default

Answer (score 1):

You init your tinymce with selector: '#mytextarea' but your html not include this id, you should first add id on textarea:

```
<textarea name="content" id="mytextarea"></textarea>
```

about myFileBrowser function, it's in right place.

Comment: Ok thanks, but now a have a "big" textarea, like CKEditor, but I haven't the filemanager interface, like if tiny as if he had priority.

Comment: If you want the filemanager interface on its own, you can just use an iframe `<iframe src="{{ path('file_manager', {conf: 'yourconf'}) }}"></iframe>`. Otherwise it's normal if you see TinyMCE, you have to browse to the file-manager from its interface to select a file.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to include the `id` you've tied TinyMCE to in your content. Like this:

`<textarea name="content" id="mytextarea"></textarea>`